# Replace the node's value to be the sum of all its descendents

Tags: java, binary-tree

```
private void sumNode(TNode node) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (node == null)
        return;

    sumNode(node.getLeft());
    sumNode(node.getRight());
    if (node.getLeft() != null && node.getRight() != null) {
        sum = (node.getData() + node.getLeft().getData() + node.getRight()
                .getData());
    } else if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        sum = (node.getData() + (Integer) node.getLeft().getData());
    } else if (node.getRight() != null) {
        sum = (node.getData() + node.getRight().getData());
    } else {
        sum = 0;
    }
    node.setData(sum);
}
```

I know my method is totally wrong - I have no idea how to do this.

I want to replace each node value to be the summation of all its descendants, can anyone guide me how to do?

I have ran out ideas for how to solve this problem. Even pseudocode will be appreciated.

The problem is:

- My tree has: `5 2 1 3 6 8`
- The outcome is: `0 0 2 0 6 13`,
- The expected outcome is: `0 0 4 0 8 20`

Comment: you need to make sumnode1 recursive (calling itself for the left and right items), before adjusting the current nodes value, based on it's children

Comment: Hi i have edited, I still cant get the correct answer

Comment: Your last ``else`` branch should have ``sum = node.getData()`` instead of ``sum = 0``.

Comment: Hi by right I want to sum all the descendent data only exclude the root data, is no child should replace the root with 0

Comment: Yes, but you are currently applying this rule only to leaf nodes; the updated values in nodes with children will include the _original_ value of the node plus the _new_ values in the two leaves.

Comment: I don't really understand your example; which one is the root element and which parent element belongs to which child elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to include the original value of the node in the sum, then this is very easy with recursion:

```
public void sumNode(TNode<E> root) {
    // For empty trees, do nothing.
    if (root == null)
        return;

    // Update the left subtree recursively.
    sumNode(root.left);

    // Update the right subtree recursively.
    sumNode(root.right);

    // At this point, all the elements in the left and right
    // subtrees are already summed up. Now we update the
    // sum in the root element itself.
    if (root.left != null)
        root.item += root.left.item;
    if (root.right != null)
        root.item += root.right.item;
}
```

If you do not want to include the original value, then a single recursive pass is not enough because by the time you calculate the value of a non-leaf node N with two leaves L1 and L2, the values in L1 and L2 have already been updated to zeros, so you cannot use the original values of L1 and L2 to store N. If you are allowed to add a new `originalItem` entry in the node, you can store the original value there, use my solution above and then run a final pass which subtracts the value of `originalItem` from `item` for every node in the tree:

```
private void preprocessTree(TNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null)
        return;

    preprocessTree(root.left);
    preprocessTree(root.right);
    root.originalItem = root.item;
}

private void processTree(TNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null)
        return;

    processTree(root.left);
    processTree(root.right);
    if (root.left != null)
        root.item += root.left.item;
    if (root.right != null)
        root.item += root.right.item;
}

private void postprocessTree(TNode<E> root) {
    if (root == null)
        return;

    postprocessTree(root.left);
    postprocessTree(root.right);
    root.item -= root.originalItem;
}

public void sumTree(TNode<E> root) {
    preprocessTree(root);
    processTree(root);
    postprocessTree(root);
}
```

Comment: @user236501: yes... when he's calculating root.item, he's referencing root.right + root.left, even though they may be null.. you need to add a check.

Comment: Okay, i have done the checking, but i realised example if the leaf node no child it update the node to 0 then when back track to parent node, it plus 0 but not the original value.

Comment: My tree have data : 5 2 1 3 6 8, the outcome is 0 0 2 0 6 13

Comment: Sorry guys, went to lunch and when I got back, bam, 6 new comments. :) I've updated my code to include the missing checks for null pointers. Also note that my code assumes that the "sum of all descendants" includes the node itself. If it shouldn't, then you'll have to save a copy of the original values in the nodes and subtract them from the sums later.

Comment: @Tamás: +1 from me... I think you're doing a great job of keeping track of the shifting requirement ;)

Comment: Any idea how to save a copy I create a TNode temp = node but doesn't really where is the correct position

Comment: @user236501: ``TNode temp = node`` does not copy the node, it just makes ``temp`` refer to the *same* node as ``node`` does. You can override the ``clone()`` method of the ``TNode`` class to make a deep copy of the node by creating a new node, cloning the left and right subtrees recursively, and then assigning the cloned subtrees to ``left`` and ``right`` in the new node, but that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explaination  for this line root.item -= root.originalItem;  how do i get back the originalItem?

Comment: Why do you want to get that back?

Comment: because i don't have a instance variable call originalItem

Comment: If you cannot afford to add that instance variable, and you really don't want the sum to include the value of the node itself, you need a temporary area where you store the original values. Another approach (instead of copying the tree) would be to use a ``TreeMap< TNode<E>, E>`` to store the original values. In this case, you would use ``preprocessTree`` to create and return such a ``TreeMap`` that assigns nodes to their original values, and use ``postprocessTree`` to subtract the original values from the sums.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i am getting the problem correctly given the complexity of the most accepted answer from Tamas but the following simpler code seems to work for me(correct me if i am missing a test case):

1) If you have to "exclude" the current nodes value from the sum  the use following:

```
public static int sumDesc(TreeNode root)
{
    if(root == null) return 0;

    int temp = root.data;

    root.data = sumDesc(root.leftChild)+ sumDesc(root.rightChild);

    return root.data+temp;
}
```

2) If you have to "include" the current nodes value then use following:

```
public static int sumDescInc(TreeNode root)
{
    if(root == null) return 0;

    root.data += sumDescInc(root.leftChild)+ sumDescInc(root.rightChild);

    return root.data;
}
```

Comment: The reason why my code is apparently more complicated is because the original poster wanted to *update* the tree in-place for *every* node instead of just *returning* the sum for a given node.

Comment: Even the code i have given updates the tree in-place. The line of code: root.data = sumDesc(root.leftChild)+ sumDesc(root.rightChild);  does the updates since object arguments are passed by reference in Java, the given algorithm stores the values in the node on its way up the recursion.

Comment: Ah, hang on, you are right, sorry. I was probably way too tired when I made that comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really tested this, but I think something like this should work to help get the sum of the nodes children. Then you can go through and replace each nodes value with this sum.

```
public int sum(Node node){
  return (!node.isLeaf()) ? sum(node.getLeftChild())+sum(node.getRightChild()) : node.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Since sum(X) is zero for any leaf node, it will also be zero for any non-leaf node because you are just adding zeros all the way up to the root.

Comment: Nice, sorry it has been a long time since I have played with a binary tree.  I edited my response.

Answer (score 0):

To store the sum of all descendants in the Node couples your node/tree very closely to a specific job. Wouldn't it then be better, to have the traversing and summing method in the TNode-class? Where is it now?

Another question: If you need to recalc the tree, you have to traverse the whole tree again, or you have to know, whether you already calculated the sum, and no modification of values or tree happened since then. But wouldn't it be more easy then, to calculate the sum as soon as you insert a node, so that the tree always reflects the sums? Is the data of each TNode final? Hm - it can't, if it first is the nodes own value, and later the value of the node plus all descendants.

Comment: Is an optional tutorial question, i am practising now preparing for exam, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

this code serves the purpose where the original data of left and right sub tree is added  which is stored in the corresponding node (pure recursive way)

```
int sumofnodes(Node **root)
{
    if(*root==NULL)
        return 0;
    if((*root)->left==NULL && (*root)->right==NULL)
    {
        int temp=(*root)->val;
        (*root)->val=0;
        return temp;
    }
    int sum=sumofnodes(&(*root)->left)+sumofnodes(&(*root)->right);
    int data=(*root)->val;
    (*root)->val=sum;
    return (data+sum);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe a simple solution:

```
package tree;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TreeNode<T> {
    T data;
    ArrayList<TreeNode<T>> children;
    //generics don't make array
    public TreeNode(){
        children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>(); 
    }
}

public static int sum(TreeNode<Integer> root)
{
        int s1=root.data;
        for(int i=0;i<root.children.size();i++)
            s1+=sum(root.children.get(i));

        return s1;          

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with recursion.

```
int sumNode(Node *root) {
    // For empty trees, return 0.
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    // For leaf node return its value
    if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
        return root->data;

    //calculate left subtree sum recursively
    int LST=sumNode(root->left)

    //Calculate right subtree sum recursively
    int RST=sumNode(root->right)

    // store the value of root for its parent
    int temp=root->data;

    // store the result
    root->data = LST+RST;
    return temp+LST+RST;
}
```